# BASH: Incrementing a variable using "let"

Tags: database, bash, let

I want to ask if you guys knew how can i fix my script.
I want to go positive with the let command..
any ideas ?

```
a=1
read -p "Enter any number: " COUNTER
until [ 1 -eq $COUNTER ]; do
    echo "What is the name for $COUNTER ?"
    read name1

    START=$COUNTER
    END=1
    for i in $START
    do
        echo "$i"

        echo ${name1}_$i: >> foo.sh

    done


    echo COUNTER $COUNTER
    let a\+=1

done
```

Comment: do you want to _increment_ a?

Comment: If you want to increment a you can use this : let "a=a + 1"

Comment: yes, but it doesnt work...
also when i try to increment i: let i=i + 1    
i get an error

Comment: Are you running this script with `/bin/bash` or with `/bin/sh`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to increment a variable in bash:

```
# one way
a=$((a+1))

# or even just
((a++))

# using "let"
let "a=a + 1"
```

Answering your comment, you could do

```
${name1}_$((a++))
```

or

```
${name1}_$((++a))
```

depending on whether you wanted to increment the variable *before* or *after* `echo`ing it.

Comment: trying to do that...
echo ${name1}_((a++)) >> foo.sh
But: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: @user3057030, `echo ${name1}_$((a++)) >> foo.sh` -- use `(( ))` when you want to process an arithmetic expression but don't want the result, use `$(( ))` when you do want the result (like expanding a variable)

Comment: @user3057030 No problem. You should consider editing your question to add in the information you have supplied in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

At the very top of your script there is the declaration:

```
a=1
```

that seems to cause the problem. The variable should be declared an integer, which is accomplished two ways:

```
declare -i a
```

or

```
let a=1
```

Further arithmetic can be done using another `let` declaration or double parens notation, where the `$` prefix not always has to be used like in the `for` loop:

```
for ((i=0; i<10; ++i)); do
    echo "i=$i"
done
```